# mysql update query on two tables

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, mysqli

I am trying to update two tables in one query using a query that looks like this:

```
$query = "UPDATE tblproducts, tblsideimages 
          SET tblproducts.prodCode='oj', tblsideimages.prodCode='oj' 
          WHERE tblproducts.prodCode='aj' 
              AND tblsideimages.prodCode='aj'";
```

It works if there are contents in tblsideimages such as that one but it doesn't work if tblsideimages has no contents.

The problem is that I have to make it adjust accordingly because it is not always that there will be a content in tblsideimages. Sometimes the user can add data that is inserted in tblproducts only. How can I make it that, if there is no content in tblsideimages, it will still work for tblproducts and if tblsideimages and tblproducts both has content, both will update. Thanks!

Comment: Just split it into 2 queries. There is absolutely no reason to perform it in one query (in this particular case)

Comment: @Icarus: oops, I mis-copied the condition. Well, as I said, implicit join (defined by comma-separated list of tables) is an `INNER JOIN`, thus you would get empty result set if right side of join is empty. So  `IFNULL(tblsideimages.prodCode,'aj')` won't work because `tblsideimages.prodCode` not equals to null, but it just doesn't exist (this is applied for `INNER JOIN`). Your code would work if it was `LEFT JOIN`

Answer (score 2):

There is no way (and real reason) to do all the work in one query. So just split it into:

```
UPDATE tblproducts SET prodCode='oj' WHERE prodCode='aj' 

UPDATE tblsideimages SET prodCode='oj' WHERE prodCode='aj'
```

Less queries doesn't mean "more performant", so never follow the idea to fit everything into one query.

Comment: hmm I see. I was really hoping to put everything in one query as I thought since I am using ajax, it will be better to put everything in one query..

Comment: @AJ Naidas: "1 query" is never a silver bullet. You need to perform as many queries as you need

Answer (score 0):

you could do this with a stored procedure - write a stored procedure with the update statements in a transaction.

Using rollbacks, you can ensure that they are treated as one unit of work, ie either they are all executed or none of them are, to keep data consistent.

or execute multiple queries like

```
     $query="UPDATE tblproducts
             SET tblproducts.prodCode='oj'
             WHERE tblproducts.prodCode='aj';
             UPDATE tblsideimages 
             SET tblsideimages.prodCode='oj'
             WHERE tblsideimages.prodCode='aj'";
```

Comment: 1. not every driver support multiple queries 2. your second query is wrong